Intuition for working with p-names.
So I have been trying to learn about forcing in set theory from kunen. There are these things called "p-names" which have a complicated definition in forcing. if $M$ is a countable transitive model of $ZFC$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is a poset, then $M^{\mathbb{P}}$ is the set of all p-names in $M$.
Each p-name is like a recipe for creating some set. If we evaluate a p-name "$\tau$" with respect to some generic filter "$G$", then $\tau[G]$ is also a set. Then, we can define $M[G] = \{{\tau[G] : \tau \in M^{\mathbb{P}} }\}$. This set $M[G]$ is our desired model of $ZFC$.
Now I have 2 questions.
$(1)$ I know how the mechanics of p-names work, but I can't seem to find the motivation behind them. Why did we chose this specific way to extend a model of $ZFC$ in forcing? It seems quite random to me and it is not really obvious to me how this can help up get a model of $ZFC$ (assuming we use a generic filter for the extension).
$(2)$ I find p-names quite hard and unintuitive to work with. The proofs in kunen that show that $M[G]$ is a model of $ZFC$ is sort of incomprehensible to me because not only I have no idea about how to use p-names as a tool, but I am trying too hard to keep track of which are names "$\tau$" and which are name-condition pair "$(\tau,p)$". Am I missing some kind of intuition?

I think a reasonable intuition is gained from thinking of  the members of $\mathbb P$ as 'truth values', with $p=1$ being 'true'. If $\tau,\nu$ are names and $(\nu,p)\in \tau$, this is saying that $p$ is the truth value that the set corresponding to $\nu$ belongs to the set corresponding to $\tau$. If $p=1$, this says that definitely the set for $\nu$ belongs to the set for $\tau$. The generic tells you which truth values you are going to reinterpret as true.

For question 1, let's forget about the poset entirely for the moment (it will come back later). Suppose we have a ground model $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZF}$, which for simplicity I'll assume is transitive. Now we can define the $\mathcal{M}$-class of names over $\mathcal{M}$ as the smallest $\mathcal{M}$-class $\mathcal{C}$ with the following properties:

$\emptyset\in\mathcal{C}$.

If $A\in\mathcal{M}$ and $A\subseteq\mathcal{C}$, and $f\in \mathcal{M}$ is any function with domain $A$, then $$\nu=\{\langle a, b\rangle: a\in A,b\in f(a)\}$$ is in $\mathcal{C}$.


Similarly, for every $X\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ (note that we're not assuming $X\in\mathcal{M}$ here!) and $\nu\in\mathcal{C}$ we can define $\nu[X]$ recursively as $$\nu[X]=\{\mu[X]: \exists b\in X(\langle\mu,b\rangle\in \nu)\}.$$ The point is this:

Proposition: If $\mathcal{N}$ is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ with $X\in \mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$, then for each $\nu\in\mathcal{C}$ we have $\nu[X]\in\mathcal{N}$.

Basically, everything "built by" a name has to be in the resulting model. The proof of the above fact is just a quick application of transfinite recursion, and this application reinforces the whole "names-as-recipes" idea in the linked answer.
This then raises a natural idea, letting $\mathcal{M}$ be as above:

Guess: There is some notion of "reasonable" such that for reasonable sets $X$ (and perhaps further assumptions about $\mathcal{M}$, e.g. countability) we have $\{\nu[X]:\nu\in\mathcal{C}\}\models\mathsf{ZF}$ (and so in particular is the smallest transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ containing $\mathcal{M}$ as a submodel and $X$ as an element).

This is where the whole "generic filter through some poset $\in\mathcal{M}$" finally appears; it's the reasonableness-criterion needed for making the guess above work. But right up until this final moment, we don't have to think about posets/filters at all.

Of course, the above assumes that the "names-as-recipes" idea actually clicks. For this I think the best thing to do is  actually write out some translations. For instance:

Fix some set $u\in\mathcal{M}$. Show that, for each $a\in\mathcal{M}$, there is a $\nu\in\mathcal{C}$ such that for every $X\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ with $u\in X$ we have $\nu[X]=a$. (This $u$ is basically a "default-yes" element; its role is taken by $\mathbb{1}$ in the poset.)

Again assuming that we're restricting to $X\ni u$ for some $u\in\mathcal{M}$ as above, write out the name-over-$\mathcal{M}$ corresponding to the recipe (from the linked answer) $$=\{\{\{...\}\} \mbox{($n$ many brackets)}: n\in X\}.$$


(At this point you might be wondering why I didn't use recipe-rules where the right-hand-component is/isn't a subset of, rather than an element of, the set $X$ involved; the answer is just that I wanted to stick closer to the usual definition of names.)

OK, now assuming that $X$ is a filter through some poset $\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{M}$ with greatest element $\mathbb{1}$, given $\nu,\mu\in\mathcal{C}$ find a $\rho\in\mathcal{C}$ such that we are guaranteed to have $\rho[X]=\mu[X]\cap\nu[X]$. We're still not assuming genericity here, but we are going to see how the poset structure helps us with our name constructions.

